# C# question about GetType of class

Tags: c#

I have an assembly asdf.dll and it has a class 'Class1'.

How can I get the type of Class1?

```
string a = "Class1"; //Class1 is the name of class in asdf.dll
string typeString = typeof(Class1).FullName; // here I only have the string Class1 and not Class Class1
AssemblyName assemblyName = AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName("asdf.dll");
Type type = Type.GetType(typeString + ", " + assemblyName);
```

How can I get the type of a class from a string holding the class name?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Type t = Type.GetType("MyDll.MyClass,Mydll")
```

where MyDll.MyClass is the class Location of your desire class/Form.                           Mydll is the your dll name. which u want to Call.

Comment: if i give this,
Type t = Type.GetType("asdf.dll.Class1,asdf.dll");
i.m getting null for t.?

Answer (score 3):

`typeof(Class1).FullName` is already the fully qualified name.

Try just passing that, or using the Type.Name property instead.

Comment: as i told, i cannot give typeof(Class1) as i dont have Class1 as a class. i ave it only as a string. how to use it,so that i can convert it as class

Comment: Errm, that was you code, I am pointing out what you are doing wrong.

Comment: Very odd duplicate (below, attributed to "unknown (google)"). I got this too... very  odd!)